# SQL Database Design ERD - Empty entity because of different function

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, erd

As you can see below, the `User` is able to make a `Call`, the `Operator` will log it, writing the `time` (error on my part, Column2), his `own ID` and the `ID of the caller`. The `Operator` is also able to create a `Solution`, by generating a `Solution ID` and `describing` the solution.

Note that nothing differentiate the `User` from the `Operator` in terms of attributes. Indeed they both inherit their ID from the `Person` entity.

So I have two questions.

First, as you can see, the `Call` entity has two attributes which are the same column (ID for `User` and `Operator`), but will always represent two different people (i.e. a `User` will never be an `Operator`). Is this the correct notation for such a thing?

Secondly, I am not sure about having `User` and `Operator` as separate entities because no attribute distinguish them from one another, only their ability to do something or not (`User` can't create a solution). This would mean that they don't have attributes apart from the ones they inherit. Is this correct or should the two entities be merged under the `Person`entity?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's valid to create subtypes with distinct relationships and/or constraints, even if they have no distinct attributes. You'll be able to use referential integrity to ensure that Operator IDs and User IDs don't get mixed up in the Call table, and it's possible to enforce mutual exclusion between the IDs in the User and Operator tables.

As far as notation is concerned, I would show the ID in the User and Operator tables, and use Crow's foot lines to represent the FK constraints between the tables. If I wanted to make the subtyping explicit, I would rather show that on an EER diagram using Chen's notation than on a table diagram.